# MS-DOS Batch file pause with enter key

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is it possible in MS-DOS batch file to pause the script and wait for user to hit enter key?

I wish to do this inside a for loop. After each iteration, I want the script to pause and wait for user to hit 'Enter'

Answer (score 313, accepted):

There's a `pause` command that does just that, though it's not specifically the enter key.

If you really want to wait for only the enter key, you can use the `set` command to ask for user input with a dummy variable, something like:

`set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...`

Comment: You don't need to specify a variable name: `set /p=Hit ENTER to continue...`, or simply `set /p=` if you don't need a prompt.

Comment: For some reason, my app is blasting right past the pause logic. Very strange.

Comment: It seems a bit weird to see the word "app" being used in this context (a batch file)

Comment: it does not work for me. works only from second launch when 'set' worked out  / saved into the env.

Answer (score 27):

You can do it with the `pause` command, example:

```
dir
pause
echo Now about to end...
pause
```

Comment: `pause` indeed is the only valid answer for `MS-DOS` (all other answers are working in `cmd` only). So, your answer is actually the only completely correct one for this special question (although it was already suggested more than 7 years before)

Answer (score 16):

`pause` command is what you looking for.
If you looking ONLY the case when enter is hit you can abuse the `runas` command:

```
runas /user:# "" >nul 2>&1
```

the screen will be frozen until enter is hit.What I like more than `set/p=` is that if you press other buttons than enter they will be not displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which OS you're using, if you are flexible, then `CHOICE` can be used to wait on almost any key `EXCEPT` enter

If you are really referring to what Microsoft insists on calling "Command Prompt" which is simply an MS-DOS emulator, then perhaps `TIMEOUT` may suit your purpose (`timeout /t -1` waits on any key, not just `ENTER`) and of course `CHOICE` is available again in recent WIN editions.

And a warning on `SET /P` - whereas `set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...` will work,

```
set "dummy="
set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
if defined dummy (echo not just ENTER was pressed) else (echo just ENTER was pressed)
```

will detect whether just ENTER or something else, ending in ENTER was keyed in.

Answer (score 3):

The only valid answer would be the `pause` command.

Though this does not wait specifically for the 'ENTER' key, it waits for any key that is pressed.

And just in case you want it convenient for the user, `pause` is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

[npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302467/11777065) made me aware of `runas /user:# "" >nul 2>&1` – however, I've discovered that it can be shortened significantly, thanks to an undocumented parameter alias. `2>&1` also appears to be unnecessary. This is as short as you can make it (not counting the prompt text):

```
echo|set/p="Press <ENTER> to continue.."&runas/u: "">NUL
```

It's not very readable with syntax highlighting (and stackoverflow.com still hasn't fixed their batch file syntax highlighting), so here's a screenshot with syntax highlighting:

[image: Press to continue..]

Answer (score 0):

Use [pause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pause) in your bat file without any parameters like so:

```
@echo off
echo Hello
pause
```

Running this by double-clicking it in Windows Explorer will display:

```
Hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

[screenshot of cmd running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEuZ6.png)

After pressing any key (excluding modifier keys), the code will continue and if it ends, the window will disappear.

- This is assuming non-Enter keys are also fine.
- `@echo off` [prevents the commands from being printed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19149079).