# How do I stop my batch file from printing the code it is running?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following script:

```
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (     
    IF %%i==1 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
    IF %%i==2 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
    IF %%i==3 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
)
```

I just wanted to print

```
1
2
3
```

because I will be using the same logic again to write a more complete task ... I'm not a Windows guy, and I have no idea how to do it in `batch`.
Instead I'm getting:

```
c:\>FOR %i IN (1 2 3) DO (
IF %i == 1 (ECHO %i  )
 IF %i == 2 (ECHO %i  )
 IF %i == 3 (ECHO %i  )
)

c:\>(
IF 1 == 1 (ECHO 1  )
 IF 1 == 2 (ECHO 1  )
 IF 1 == 3 (ECHO 1  )
)
1

c:\>(
IF 2 == 1 (ECHO 2  )
 IF 2 == 2 (ECHO 2  )
 IF 2 == 3 (ECHO 2  )
)
2

c:\>(
IF 3 == 1 (ECHO 3  )
 IF 3 == 2 (ECHO 3  )
 IF 3 == 3 (ECHO 3  )
)
3
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To avoid echoing the Windows commands in a batch file, use `@echo off`:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (     
    IF %%i==1 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
    IF %%i==2 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
    IF %%i==3 ( 
       ECHO %%i 
    )
)
```

Note the preceding `@` in `echo off` prevents `echo off` from echoing. If you don't have the `@` then you'll see `echo off` echoed to the terminal but then echoing will be off after that point. A batch file command which is preceded by `@` is not echoed. So `@` can be used to prevent echoing of individual commands.